# Is there a way to make saveAll() remove extraneous objects?

Tags: php, cakephp, transactions

My host object hasMany option objects associated with it. In the edit form, users can (de)select options and save that new set of associations. This is implemented using saveAll() on the posted data. The result is that

- the host (main) object is updated,
- option (associated) objects that are included both in the prior and the new association are updated, and
- option objects that were not included in the prior association but are included in the new one are created.

But what does not happen is

- that option objects that were included in the prior association but not in the new one are deleted.

**Question:** Can saveAll() do that as well, and how would the data structure have to look like to achieve this effect?

Related information:

My code to handle the edit form is actually more complex (hence I haven't quoted it here) but it results in the data structure as described in the book:

```
( [Host] => ( ... host object fields ... ),
  [Option] => ( [0] => ( ... first option object fields ... ),
                ...
                [n] => ( ... nth option object fields ... )
              )
)
```

Now, if the original host had an associated option that is not included in the 0..n array then saveAll() won't detect this and won't delete that associated object.

Not sure if this is relevant but I am using CakePHP 1.3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HABTM` deletes all associated records then recreates what is needed. As [PawelMysior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244751/pawelmysior) suggests, you could achieve this with your `hasMany` by manually deleting the associated records immediately before the save. The danger, though, is that the save fails you lose the previous state.

I would go with a variant of [GJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109799/gj)'s solution and delete them after a successful save, but instead loop over an array of redundant IDs and use Cake's Model->del() method. This way you retain all the built-in error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will delete the extra records manually then and probably add manually too, eliminating the setup for saveAll() alltogether (the datasource does not support atomic changes, so that point in favour of saveAll() is moot).

Comment: I rarely use saveAll - I prefer to retain control.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an elegant solution but works for me.

```
if ($this->Main->saveAll($this->data))
{
    $this->Main->query(sprintf(
        'DELETE '
        . 'FROM extraneous '
        . 'WHERE main_id = \'%s\' AND modified < (SELECT modified FROM main WHERE id = \'%1$s\')'
        , mysql_real_escape_string($this->Main->id)
    ));
}
```

Note that your tables need to have a [modified](http://book.cakephp.org/view/69/created-and-modified) field.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that everything gets executed atomically if you manually wrap everything into a transaction.

This can be done with the `begin()`, `rollback()` and `commit()` methods of the datasource:

```
$this->Main->begin();

if ( !$this->Main->save(...) ) {
  $this->Main->rollback();
  return false;
}

// Perform saves in related models...
if ( !$this->Main->MainRelatedModel->save(...) ) {
  $this->Main->rollback();
  return false;
}

// Perform deletes in extraneous records...
if ( !$this->Main->MainRelatedModel->delete(...) ) {
  $this->Main->rollback();
  return false;
}

// Everything went well, commit and close the transaction
$this->Main->commit();
```

The main disadvantage here is that transactions cannot be nested, hence you cannot use `saveAll()`. You have to save/delete everything step by step, instead of doing it in a single call.

Comment: This answer is old but still helps me fixing my problems with cake. Thank you @elitalon!

Answer (score 1):

`saveAll()` wont delete anything from your database.

I guess the best way is to delete options related to the current host before saving, and then adding them. If however, you need to update those that already exists (do you?) for some reason (like: options being related to some other models), I guess you can try to write a piece of code, that will delete unselected options.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this, I noticed there still isn't a solution built-in CakePHP. To achieve this, I added the following code to my model:

```
private $oldBarIds = array();
public function beforeSave($options = array() {
    parent::beforeSave($options);

    $this->oldBarIds = array();
    if ($this->id && $this->exists() && isset($this->data['Bar'])) {
        $oldBars = $this->Bar->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('id'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Bar.foo_id' => $this->id
            )
        ));
        $this->oldBarIds = Hash::extract($oldBars, '{n}.id');
    }
}
```

This checks if `Bar` exists in the saving data. If it does, it'll get the current id's of the current ones, setting them to `$this->oldBarIds`. Then when the save succeeds, it should delete the old ones:

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    parent::afterSave($created, $options);

    if (!$created && $this->oldBarIds) {
        $this->Bar->deleteAll(array(
            'Bar' => $this->oldBarIds
        ));
    }
}
```

This way the deletion is handled by the model, and only occurs when the save succeeded. Should be able to add this to a behavior, might do this some day.