# CakePHP saveAll() does not delete or update join table

Tags: cakephp, model-associations

I want the join table to be updated/deleted automatically. I'm doing a deleteAll() prior to saveAll() as a workaround to do this.

When I submit the form, the Layout and Component models updates correctly but the Layout Component model (which is the join table) inserts new data (which is what I want) but does not delete the referenced data.

Layout Model:

```
class Layout extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Layout';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'LayoutComponentOrder' => array(
            'className' => 'LayoutComponentOrder',
            'foreignKey' => 'layout_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'order' => 'LayoutComponentOrder.sort_id ASC',
        ),
        'ComponentVideo' => array(
            'className' => 'ComponentVideo',
            'foreignKey' => 'layout_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
);}
```

Component Model:

```
class ComponentVideo extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'ComponentVideo';
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $hasMany = array(
        'LayoutComponentOrder' => array(
            'className' => 'LayoutComponentOrder',
            'foreignKey' => 'layout_component_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
    );

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Layout' => array(
            'className'    => 'Layout',
            'foreignKey'    => 'layout_id'
        ),
    );
};
```

Layout Component Model (join table):

```
class LayoutComponentOrder extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'LayoutComponentOrder';
    var $uses = 'layout_component_orders'; 

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $belongsTo = array(
            'Layout' => array(
                'className'    => 'Layout',
                'foreignKey'    => 'layout_id'
            ),
            'ComponentVideo' => array(
                'className'    => 'ComponentVideo',
                'foreignKey'    => 'layout_component_id'
            )
        );
}
```

Layout Controller:

```
// deleting the data manually
$this->LayoutComponentOrder->deleteAll(array('LayoutComponentOrder.layout_id' => $layout_id));
// this one inserts into the tables including the join table        
$this->Layout->id = $layout_id;
if ($this->Layout->saveAll($this->data)) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The layout has been saved', true));
}
```

How can I have the join be deleted automatically? Is this possible with CakePHP?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not built into CakePHP's saveAll for hasMany relationships.  I wish it was, as I found this page searching for a solution to the same thing.

It does seem to be built in with HABTM relationships, though.

See [Is there a way to make saveAll() remove extraneous objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088013/is-there-a-way-to-make-saveall-remove-extraneous-objects) and [Shouldn't saveAll remove associated records as well?)](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Shouldn-t-saveAll-remove-associated-records-as-well-td1312792.html).

You'll have to implement your own solution (My quick solution running a deleteAll before the saveAll if the form validates.  This is not ideal though, because if there is an error not-related to form validation you lose the existing associated items).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but are we talking about removing joins when a parent record is removed from Cake? It does do that, if configured in the model relationships using the 'dependent' parameter:

> dependent: When the dependent key is set to true, and the model’s
>   delete() method is called with the cascade parameter set to true,
>   associated model records are also deleted. In this case, we set it
>   true so that deleting a User will also delete her associated Profile.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Is that what you're looking for?